# Looping a Student T-Test and Chi-Squared with Missing Data in R

Tags: r, loops, chi-squared

I am trying to use R to run a student t-test and a chi squared test with large data sets. Since I am fairly new to R my inexperience has been preventing much success in my own code.

Both data sets have missing data and look something like this:

```
 AA               assayX activity        assayY1 activity      assayY2 activity
  chemical 1           TRUE                       0                12.2    
  chemical 2           TRUE                                        0
  chemical 3                                      45.2             35.6
  chemical 4           FALSE                      0                0 

 AB                assayX activity        assayY1 activity       assayY2 activity
 chemical 1           TRUE                       FALSE             TRUE
 chemical 2           TRUE                                         FALSE
 chemical 3                                      TRUE              TRUE  
 chemical 4           FALSE                      FALSE             FALSE
```

Since it is a large data set I am trying to create a code where I can compare assayX to all assayYs. I'm hoping to create a student t-test loop for the first data set, and a chi squared loop to come the second data set. I had previously been successful creating a loop code for a correlation analysis, so I based my code off of that idea.

```
x<- na.omit(mydata1[, c(assayX)])
y<- na.omit(mydata1[, c(assayY1:assayYend)])
lapply(y, function(x)t.test(y~x))

x<-na.omit(mydata2[, c(assayX)])
y<- na.omit(mydata2[, c(assayY1:assayYend)]
lapply(y, x=x, chisq.test)
```

Problem with the first code is:
Invalid variable y

Problem with the second code is:
x and y must have the same length

I've done small tweaks here and there and have just got different types of errors like not enough 'y' observations and so on. I've been primarily using this site to figure out how work R, so I'm hoping you guys will have a clever little solution for a new guy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After a long time and gaining experience in R, I can answer my own question. First is to make the datafile change blanks to NA.

```
df1 <- read.csv("data2.csv", header=T, na.strings=c("","NA"))
```

Then for the student.t

```
df1.p= rep(NA, 418) 
 for (i in length(df1$Assays)){
test= t.test(df1[,c(i)]~df1$assay.activity)
current.p.val= test$p.value
p.df1[i]=current.p.val
 }
```

Then to add a Pearson's or Chi sq (not actually appropriate for this dataset, but just as an ex)

```
df1.p.2= rep(NA, length(df1$Assays))
df1.r.2= rep(NA, length(df1$Assays))
 for (i in length(df1$Assays)){
   test2= cor.test(df1$assay.activity, df1[,c(i)], mehtod='pearson')
   current.p.val2= test2$p.value
   current.rval = test2$estimate
   df1.p.2[i] = current.p.val2
   df1.r.2[i] = current.rval
 }
df2= cbind(df1$Assays, df1.p, df1.p.2, df1.r.2)
```

I then filtered it for only assays with 0.1 significance, but that wasn't the question here. If you want to know that, just ask a question and I'll post an answer there :)

Answer (score 0):

I don't think your data is being passed correctly to the test. t.test has arguments for whether the data is paired or not (default is false) and how to handle NAs should you want to change from the defalt. You should probably use those rather than omit NAs up front. An example with NAs in the data:

```
set.seed(1)
y <- runif(30, 0, 1)
y.NA <- c(3,24,27)
y[y.NA] <- NA
x <- runif(30, 0, 1)
x.NA <- c(1,3,8,12,21)
x[x.NA] <- NA
t.test(x,y)
```

For chisq.test you can use the table function.
chisq.test(table(x,y))$p.value

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I get an error for the chi squared test saying the x and y values must be the same length and variable lengths differ error for the t-test as well. Anyway around it?

Comment: I think the problem is in how the dataset is constructed and being sent to the hypothesis tests. I will update with a test data set.